# How do you upload a file to website?

Tags: php, upload, system

Hey guys I want to make a file uploader on my website but i don't know how.

if someone could get me off to a start with a basic code or point me to a resource i would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a browse button which can upload a file.To do that put this in your html or PHP

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
```

In the PHP which 'll handle the upload

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 { $dir="yourdirectory";
   $tmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   $targetname="name you want to give";
 }
```

and use the move_uploaded_file function as

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp,$dir."/".$targetname);
```

also you will need to check for failed uploads and other errors.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP Manual has [a whole section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) devoted to this.

The tl;dr of it is that there is a special type of `<input>` element you can use in your HTML that tells the browser you expect a file and it takes care of the mess of locating the file, etc. You then POST this to your script in a normal HTML `<form>` and it appears inside the `$_FILES` superglobal in PHP. The file itself gets sent to a temporary file on the server, and the `$_FILES` superglobal contains all sorts of information on the state of the transfer and the location and information of the files transmitted.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

The PHP documentation has [a whole section on handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), complete with examples.  I'd suggest starting there.

Answer (score 0):

I find the php tutorials are a bit hard to follow for beginners. Try the following:
http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_upload_file.cfm